# How to structure Terraform so underlying AWS resources can be referenced across applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, terraform

I'm using Terraform to create AWS ECS resources. I'm planning to deploy two applications as Docker containers that share the same ECS Cluster so that I can have multi-tenancy on the EC2 instances.

I have three separate Git repos with respective Terraform files in them:

1. Underlying ECS resources shared across the 2 apps - i.e. ECS Cluster, ec2 instance, Security Group, ASG, Launch Configuration etc.
2. First application. As well as the source code I have the Terraform configurations that creates the ECS Service, Task, ELB, ELB's security group etc which depend on resources created by repo 1.
3. Second application. Similar repo 2 with same set of AWS resources created and leveraging AWS resources created by repo 1.

Repos 2 and 3 depend on repo 1. To be specific, repo 1 creates the ECS Cluster. This is referenced when creating the ECS Service in repos 2 and 3. Right now I've hard coded the ARN but I'd like to remove the hard coded value. Is this possible? Do I need to structure my projects and Terraform separately or differently?

Furthermore, there's actually a circular dependency as ideally repo 1 would also know about resources created in repos 2 and 3. Specifically I'd like the ec2 Security Groups (SG) to open ports for the ELB SG. If this is also possible then that would be awesome.

Comment: To clarify, you're storing your applications' Terraform configurations in their own repos?  Terraform seems to expect that all resources with interdependent outputs be in the same directory, and thus map to the same statefile.  You may need a tool that can (somewhat dynamically, unfortunately), read from the statefile of another application.  (I've been wondering how to solve a similar situation.  We do use an S3 bucket for all our statefiles, which makes it easier, but pulling the statefile and extracting from it still feels hack-ish.)

Comment: Yes that's exactly my use case. So you've solved your solution by pulling state files from other Terraform configs? Do you parse the state file manually for the arn or output values that you need? Or does Terraform read from the state files if they're in the directory and you're then able to reference them in your .tf file as usual i.e. like "${aws_elb.my_elb.name}"

Comment: I haven't actually implemented this yet (still migrating existing infrastructure to Terraform slowly), but hopefully I can add `output` definitions for the resources I need, and then in the wrapper Rakefile I already have, pull the tfstate files needed from the S3 bucket, use `terraform output -state=<statefile> aws_elb.my_elb.name` or parse the tfstate JSON directly, put the data in, probably, a module (while terraform configs can get information from a file, they cannot yet run a command AFAIK), and populate that way.  Yeah, it's crufty.

Comment: I just came across this article and `remote state`. If you have your state files already in s3 looks like you may be able to refer to it directly:

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/r/remote_state.html

- https://charity.wtf/2016/03/30/terraform-vpc-and-why-you-want-a-tfstate-file-per-env/

Comment: Nice!  Definitely makes it easier.  Yeah, we have separate VPCs per environment, and I want to keep their Terraform configs separate to prevent stupid stuff happening to prod, but there is a peered VPC with our admin/monitoring stuff that needs to be referred to by each.